# How to create and delete a component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-dom

I have a problem creating and removing components in react with reactDom

I'm trying to destroy the popup component from its class but it gives me a warning

```
// file: successfull.js
mostrarPopUp(enterprise) {
        let contenedor = document.getElementById('popup');
        ReactDOM.render(<Popup empresa={enterprise} />, contenedor);
}

// file: popup.js
closeComponent() {
        console.log("Destruir componente");
        let element = document.getElementById("contenedorpop");
        let container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
}
```

i have the next warning

```
Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by React and is not a top-level container. You may have accidentally passed in a React root node instead of its container.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be rendering it based on a boolean value i.e

```
 { this.state.shouldIRender === true ?  <Popup empresa={enterprise} /> : null }
```

and in closeComponent

```
closeComponent() {
   this.setState({
    shouldIRender: false
   })
}
```